# How to duplicate Python dataframe one by one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` as follows:

```
df1 = 
    a    b
0   1    2
1   3    4
```

I'd like to make this three times to become:

```
df2 =
    a    b
0   1    2
0   1    2
0   1    2
1   3    4
1   3    4
1   3    4
```

`df2` is made from a loop, but it is not efficient.

How can I get `df2` from `df1` using a matrix way which is faster?

Comment: *"one by one"* doesn't say whether you mean by row or by column. You want to duplicate each **row** n times.

Answer (score 5):

Build a one dimensional indexer to slice both the the `values` array and `index`.  You must take care of the index as well to get your desired results.

- use `np.repeat` on an `np.arange` to get the indexer
- construct a new dataframe using this indexer on both values and the index

---

```
r = np.arange(len(df)).repeat(3)
pd.DataFrame(df.values[r], df.index[r], df.columns)

   a  b
0  1  2
0  1  2
0  1  2
1  3  4
1  3  4
1  3  4
```

Comment: You mean when the wives of the big guns insist they do something other than answer questions on SO :-)

Comment: Yes exactly. Mine had to drive our daughter to her senior prom over an hour away, so i was free...

Answer (score 3):

You can use np.repeat

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values,[3,3], axis = 0), columns = df.columns)
```

You get

```
    a   b
0   1   2
1   1   2
2   1   2
3   3   4
4   3   4
5   3   4
```

Time testing:

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values,[3,3], axis = 0))
1000 loops, best of 3: 235 µs per loop

%timeit pd.concat([df] * 3).sort_index()
best of 3: 1.26 ms per loop
```

Numpy is definitely faster in most cases so no surprises there

EDIT: I am not sure if you would be looking for repeating indices but incase you do,

```
pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values,3, axis = 0), index = np.repeat(df.index, 3), columns = df.columns)
```

Comment: You are missing the index being repeated as well

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if it is more efficient than your loop, but it easy enough to construct as:

**Code:**

```
pd.concat([df] * 3).sort_index()
```

**Test Code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('ab'))
print(pd.concat([df] * 3).sort_index())
```

**Results:**

```
   a  b
0  1  2
0  1  2
0  1  2
1  3  4
1  3  4
1  3  4
```

Comment: You nailed the index as well... even if it is slower.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with parameter scalar `3` and then add `columns` parameter to [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, 3, axis=0), columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  1  2
3  3  4
4  3  4
5  3  4
```

If really want duplicated index what can complicated some pandas functions like [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) which failed:

```
r = np.repeat(np.arange(len(df.index)), 3)
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values[r], df.index[r], df.columns)
print (df)
   a  b
0  1  2
0  1  2
0  1  2
1  3  4
1  3  4
1  3  4
```

Comment: Plust one from me!

Answer (score 0):

Not the fastest (not the slowest either) but the shortest solution so far.

```
#Build a index array and extract the rows to build the desired new df. This handles index and data all at once.    
df.iloc[np.repeat(df.index,3)]

Out[270]: In [271]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
0  1  2
0  1  2
1  3  4
1  3  4
1  3  4
```